# CSS3 Background Size "Zoom"

Tags: css

I am trying to implement a full page background image as discussed [here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

I am using the first method, the CSS3 technique. However, when I use `background-size: cover` like the author suggests, the image is "zoomed" in way farther than it needs to be and I don't understand why.

Is it a problem with the size of the image or do I have something else wrong?

[Here](http://achingarmspgh.herokuapp.com/) is a link to the page.
achievable I want to see the entire tree, trunk and all. I've already tried setting the `background-size` to "100% auto" and the effect is the same. I've also already tried `background-size` to "contain" and now the image is too small.

No JavaScript solutions please. I *know* this achievable with just CSS.

**UPDATE**

Contain looks good on a desktop site, but it looks bad on a phone/table. Cover looks good on a phone/table but bad on a desktop. I guess I'll use the one that looks the best on each device?

**UPDATE**

I think I could use contain across the board, I would just have to resize the bg image to be thinner for smaller devices.

Comment: checkout the screenshot I attached, It doesn't look small on my screen. It is dependent on screen dimensions.

Comment: You can use different background for small devices and detect it using media queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `background-size: cover` to `background-size: contain`

It looks perfect this way!

[image]

Comment: @edd I don't think that the original poster cared about IE he's using `background-size` anyway

Answer (score 3):

I believe we can suffice this requirement by using following two Solutions:

a. Use background-size:100% 100%; I am able to zoom image properly by using this Solution.
b. Use img tag with height and width as 100%